Prove that the union of two subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ iff one of the subspaces is contained in the other,
Let $V_1$,$V_2$ both be subspaces of $V$
We must show; $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace $\Longleftrightarrow V_1\subset V_2$ or $V_2\subset V_1$
(1) $V_2\subset V_1$ or $V_1\subset V_2 \Longrightarrow $ $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace
Suppose $V_2\subset V_1$ then $V_1\cup V_2=V_1$ which is a subspace.
(2) $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace $\Longrightarrow V_1\subset V_2$ or $V_2\subset V_1$
Suppose not, we claim if $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace $\Longrightarrow $ neither $V_1\subset V_2$ nor $V_2\subset V_1$
This means $u\in V_1,u\notin V_2 $ and $w\in V_2,w\notin V_1 $ for some $u$ and $w$.
But $u,w\in V_1\cup V_2$ so $w+u\in V_1\cup V_2$ . This implies $u+w\in V_1$ or $u+w\in V_2 $. Which implies $u,w\in V_1$ or $u,w\in V_2 $ a contradiction! Q.E.D
Afterthoughts: The proof of (2) feels a bit fishy to me. I tried a proof by contradiction, but I don't now if I negated it correctly. (I did $p\Longrightarrow \neg q$ instead of $\neg q\Longrightarrow \neg p$). Any help would be appreciated.

Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049546/prove-that-if-a-union-of-two-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-is-a-subspace-then-on?rq=1

The negation is not "if $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace $\implies$ neither $V_1\subset V_2$ nor $V_2\subset V_1$". Setting aside the incorect use of "if" (the statement gives the whole implication as a premise, and has no consequent), the negation of "If p then q" is not "if p then not(q)." The correct negation is "p and not(q)", i.e., "$V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace, and neither $V_1\subset V_2$ nor $V_2\subset V_1$".

@ArturoMagidin,I see so this follows from $P\Longrightarrow Q\equiv \neg Q\vee P $ and the negation is $\neg (\neg Q\vee P)\equiv Q\wedge \neg P$

I should've just said "Suppose $V_1\cup V_2$ is a subspace and  neither $V_1\subset V_2$ nor $V_2\subset V_1$." Other then that my proof is correct.
